# moment.js, comparing diff with days vs year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this two ways to decide if some difference of time is greater or equal than 1 year. I have the comparison with days and year, and I want to know if there is some problem with any of them, and which one to use.

```
// this date is an example date, it could be any from last 20 years
const userDateOld = '2001-10-20T00:00:00.000+00:00';

const dateOld = moment.utc(userDateOld);
const ruleDate = moment.utc().subtract({year: 1}).endOf('year');

const antiquityYears = ruleDate.diff(dateOld, 'years');
if (antiquityYears >= 1) { // at least 1 year to 31 december last year
  console.log('Yes, it has at least 1 year to 31 dec last year');
}

const contractedDays = ruleDate.diff(dateOld, 'days');
if (contractedDays >= 365) { // should be the same but comparing year
  console.log('Yes, it ALSO has at least 1 year to 31 dec last year');
}
```

I have this fiddle to test the code: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/9bpkLuhz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Year is the better solution as it factors in leap years, which a constant of `365` days does **not**.

The reference for this can be found at the [Moment.js Docs Page](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

You can see an example of this below:

```js
const coreDate = moment.utc.now;

const dateOld = moment.utc(coreDate);
const ruleDate = moment.utc(coreDate).subtract({year: 5});

const antiquityYears = dateOld.diff(ruleDate, 'years');
const contractedDays = dateOld.diff(ruleDate, 'days');
console.log("years passed :"+antiquityYears);
console.log("days passed :"+contractedDays);
console.log("years passed /5 :"+(antiquityYears/5));
console.log("days passed /365 :"+(contractedDays/365));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought that but I was testing with years with 366 days and the result is the same, I don't get it.

Comment: @pmiranda In your example you don't dispaly the values each equation gives you, you only compare them to an exact value ,which is very easy to get wrong. E.G Years might be perfect, and days might be over the threshold of 365*5, but both will display as correct.
My solution actually displays the difference between the two, showing that 5 years does not exactly divide between 365 days, but DOES divide between 5 years